# PHP: scandir can't open valid path

Tags: php, path, scandir

I'm currently experiencing a strange error: I'd like a little PHP script to scan a folder for all available files with

```
$path = $this->baseurl . "/images/slideshow";
$files = scandir($path);
```

but I always get an error saying it can't find the specified path...

Strangely, when I'm loading images from this directory like

```
<div><img u="image" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/images/slideshow/01.jpg" /></div>
```

it works perfectly fine! I've already tried hardcoding that path, using and not using leading and tailing slashes, using the complete website URL but nothing seemed to work. I've also put all these path versions into the is_dir() function and it always returned FALSE, but according to some forum posts, this can be due to insufficuent access rights...

The current installation of the page is running on XAMPP (standard, out-of-the-box configuration) but it behaved the same way on the FTP server...

Does anyone have an idea what could be the issue here? Could it also be an access rights problem? If yes, is there an alternative the retrieve all file names in a directoy?

Cheers, Silas

Answer (score 1):

Because `scandir` needs a server path, not a URL.

For example:

```
$path = '/var/httpd/site.com/images/slideshow';
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you ;-) I'm now using '$path = getcwd() . "/images/slideshow" ' and it works as expected =)